# Angularjs Error Logging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Currently using the stacktrace.js for logging all my errors in my Angularjs app as below

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['errorLogService',function (errorLogService) {

  return function (exception, cause) {

    errorLogService.log(exception.message, cause);

    };

}
]);
```

this service will log every error occurred in my app. My question is, can we choose certain types or levels of errors to be logged? I'm pretty sure that I'm logging every damn thing! which is causing a lot of headaches..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK stacktrace.js has no feature to specify certain types or levels of errors to be logged. That is because JS has no standard error type or error level. A script error is an error - that's all! Having said that - problem seems to be in your coding style. Why should there be so many errors thrown in JS code? So many errors in JS code will clutter the whole console and make the logging useless. Only solution I can think of is to fix the errors so that the logs get cleaner. There should be zero such errors in console before you go live - if you have tested your code properly.